# Logical Operators, || or OR?

Tags: php, operators, logical-operators, or-operator

I remember reading a while back in regards to logical operators that in the case of `OR`, using `||` was better than `or` (or vice versa).

I just had to use this in my project when it came back to me, but I can't remember which operator was recommended or if it was even true.

Which is better and why?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

There is no "better" but the more common one is `||`. They have different [**precedence**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and `||` would work like one would expect normally.

See also: [**Logical operators**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (*the following example is taken from there*):

```
// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

Comment: and `$e = true || $x = 'foo'` will not define `$x` because of short-circuiting, not because of higher precedence.

Comment: It is also worth noting that these *always* return a boolean value, unlike many other languages where they return the last value checked. So in PHP (27 || 0) returns *true*, not *27*.

Comment: @TextGeek, "these"? `27 or 0` returns `27` for me.

Comment: @Jānis Elmeris -- you are correct, I should have referred only to the "||" case.

Comment: @TextGeek, actually, you are right that `or` returns boolean as well. Just its precedence is so low that it sometimes _looks_ like it does something else. :) `print 27 or 0` would print `27` because `or` happens _after_ `print 27`. BTW, `echo` is not fooled – `echo 27 or 0` would output `1`.

Comment: @TextGeek, out of curiosity, can you name a few examples of such languages? In all the languages that I know (27 | 0) performs a bitwise-or operation and the result will be 27, but in C/C++, for example, (27 || 0) will return 1 (or true), C# (or Java) will not allow such operation because the || operator can only be applied to boolean operands and neither 27 nor 0 are such.

Comment: @nurchi -- I started checking various languages, then found [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation] has a nice list. The languages listed as returning "last value" are Javascript, Julia, Lasso, Lisp, Lua, Scheme, Perl, Ruby, POSIX shell,
Python. shell languages are a little weird, but I tried "return 5 || 10" from a zsh function and got 5.

Answer (score 51):

They are used for different purposes and in fact have different operator precedences.  The `&&` and `||` operators are intended for Boolean conditions, whereas `and` and `or` are intended for control flow.

For example, the following is a Boolean condition:

```
if ($foo == $bar && $baz != $quxx) {
```

This differs from control flow:

```
doSomething() or die();
```

Comment: `die()` function will be called if `doSomething()` will return `false` or `null`? What if `doSomething()` returns `true` or nothing?

Comment: `doSomething()` is evaluated as a boolean. If it returns a value PHP considers truthy (`true`, a non-empty string, etc.), it will not call `die()`.

Answer (score 37):

The difference between respectively || and OR and && and AND is [**operator precedence**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) :

#### `$bool = FALSE || TRUE;`

- interpreted as `($bool = (FALSE || TRUE))`
- value of `$bool` is `TRUE`

---

#### `$bool = FALSE OR TRUE;`

- interpreted as `(($bool = FALSE) OR TRUE)`
- value of `$bool` is `FALSE`

---

#### `$bool = TRUE && FALSE;`

- interpreted as `($bool = (TRUE && FALSE))`
- value of `$bool` is `FALSE`

---

#### `$bool = TRUE AND FALSE;`

- interpreted as `(($bool = TRUE) AND FALSE)`
- value of `$bool` is `TRUE`

Comment: I tested in PHP-7 `$var = false || 'pin';` and the result (`var_dump($var);`) is: **bool(true)**

Comment: @csr-nontol that's because 'pin' evaluates to true. the result of operators || and OR is always boolean, and their operands are converted to boolean before evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

Source: http://wallstreetdeveloper.com/php-logical-operators/

Here is sample code for working with logical operators:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Logical</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $a = 10;
        $b = 20;
        if ($a>$b)
        {
            echo " A is Greater";
        }
        elseif ($a<$b)
        {
            echo " A is lesser";
        }
        else
        {
             echo "A and B are equal";
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        $c = 30;
        $d = 40;
        //if (($a<$c) AND ($b<$d))
        if (($a<$c) && ($b<$d))
        {
            echo "A and B are larger";
        }
        if (isset($d))
            $d = 100;
        echo $d;
        unset($d);
    ?>
    <?php
        $var1 = 2;
        switch($var1)
        {
            case 1:  echo "var1 is 1";
                     break;
            case 2:  echo "var1 is 2";
                     break;
            case 3:  echo "var1 is 3";
                     break;
            default: echo "var1 is unknown";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old topic but still. I've just met the problem in the code I am debugging at work and maybe somebody may have similar issue...

Let's say the code looks like this:

```
$positions = $this->positions() || [];
```

You would expect (as you are used to from e.g. javascript) that when $this->positions() returns false or null, $positions is empty array. But it isn't. The value is TRUE or FALSE depends on what $this->positions() returns.

If you need to get value of $this->positions() or empty array, you have to use:

```
$positions = $this->positions() or [];
```

---

**EDIT:**

The above example doesn't work as intended but the truth is that `||` and `or` is not the same... Try this:

```
<?php

function returnEmpty()
{
  //return "string";
  //return [1];
  return null;
}

$first = returnEmpty() || [];
$second = returnEmpty() or [];
$third = returnEmpty() ?: [];

var_dump($first);
var_dump($second);
var_dump($third);
echo "\n";
```

This is the result:

```
bool(false)
NULL
array(0) {
}
```

So, actually the third option `?:` is the correct solution when you want to set returned value or empty array.

```
$positions = $this->positions() ?: [];
```

Tested with PHP 7.2.1

Comment: it's incorrect answer, the second example works exactly as first one

Comment: @WayFarer well, it's not correct (there is an issue) but you're wrong too (|| and OR is not the same) - see my edit

Comment: right, operators || and 'or' have different priority, so, your second example works as: (($second = returnEmpty()) or []); So, the answer to original question would be || is better, always use it, until you really understand why do you want to use 'or'

Comment: `$positions = $this->positions() ?? [];` is likely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one is inherently better than another one, but I would suggest sticking with || because it is the default in most languages.

EDIT: As others have pointed out there is indeed a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing bad or better, It just depends on the precedence of operators. Since `||` has higher precedence than `or`, so `||` is mostly used.

Answer (score -4):

Some languages use short-circuit, and others use full Boolean evaluation (if you know, this is similar to the directive `$B` in Pascal).

Explanations:

```
function A(){
    ...Do something..
    return true;
}

function B(){
    ...Do something..
    return true;
}

if ( A() OR B() ) { .....
```

In this example the function `B()` will never be executed. Since the function `A()` returns TRUE, the result of the OR statement is known from the first part without it being necessary to evaluate the second part of the expression.

However with `( A() || B() )`, the second part is always evaluated regardless of the value of the first.

For optimized programming, you should always use `OR` which is faster (except for the case when the first part returns `false` and second part actually needs to be evaluated).

Comment: This is not 'The Best Answer !!'. Please scroll back up and take the most up voted answer for a good explanation. With the `||`, `B` will not be called. Both operators do exactly the same, except that the precedence is differs.

Comment: "you should always use OR which is faster" Hmm, i wonder if this is true... so let's check that: https://3v4l.org/5QSAA/vld#tabs https://3v4l.org/PdjJP/vld#tabs The number of opcodes is the same. So it doesn't matter performance wise.