# if statement formatting

Tags: php, if-statement

Basically, I always use words 'and' & 'or' so, my scripts look like:

```
if ($value == '1' or $value == '2' or $value == '3') {
    //do stuff
}


if ($value == '1' and $user_logged == 'Admin') {
    //do stuff
}
```

1. It's possible get rid of of `$value` repeating?
2. Any benefit in using `and` and `or` instead of `||` and `&&` ?

Comment: you can use `if ($val>=1 && $val<=3){}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to shortcut expressions like

```
if ($value == 1 or 2 or 3) // invalid
```

But you can check the values in another way:

```
if (in_array($value, array(1, 2, 3))) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The difference between `or` and || is [operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or). Use || and &&, not `or` and `and`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer 1.

```
$inArray = (1,2,3);
if (in_array($value,$inArray)) {
    //  do stuff
}
```

Answer 2.

[Operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use first if as a switch statement:

```
switch($value) {
   case "1":
      echo "value is 1";
      break;
   case "2":
      echo "value is 2";
      break;
   case "3":
      echo "value is 3";
      break;
}
```

Answer to your second question: [Operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: just to be precise: there **is** difference

Comment: they have different precedence