# What is the difference between the OR and || operator in PHP?

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logical Operators, || or OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or)

I've always thought that OR is another way of writing the || operator in PHP. The only way I prefer using OR over || is that it makes the code easier to read since || can be confused with II or 11 or whatever...

One day I stumbled upon this thing though:

```
<?php 
      $a = 'string_b';
      $active = ($a == 'string_a') OR
                ($a == 'string_b') OR
                ($a == 'string_c');  
   var_dump($active); // Prints FALSE;
?>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference is operator priority, see [Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `||` has a higher priority than `OR`.

By the way, `var_dump($a)` **returns** `null` but **prints** the right thing, `string_b`.
But, `var_dump($active)` will indeed produce an unexpected result, `false`.
In fact, `=` has higher priority than `or`, so your code is equivalent to:

```
($active = ($a == 'string_a')) OR ($a == 'string_b') OR ($a == 'string_c');
```

It first assigns `false` to active, then execute the right part of the first `OR`.

Comment: Did a mistake up there... Corrected it

Answer (score 2):

It's the same. But `||` has higher precedence than `OR`
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 1):

= has a higher precedence than OR. So, $active = ($a == 'string_a') is evaluated first, which is false. Enclose the entire right hand side in it's own set of brackets and you'll get the result you were expecting.

```
<?php 
      $a = 'string_b';
      $active = (
                 ($a == 'string_a') OR
                 ($a == 'string_b') OR
                 ($a == 'string_c')
                );
   var_dump($active); // Prints TRUE;
?>
```