# php why does or operator return 0 as true

Tags: php

In the following code:

```
$a = 0 or 1;
$b = 0 || 1; 
echo "$a, $b"; // 0, 1
```

Why does `$a` equal zero, I thought `or` and `||` were interchangeable in PHP?
What exactly is going on with the `or` statement to make it return `0`?

I would have assume both results would have been `1` making it echo `1, 1`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998330/1316350

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical Operators, || or OR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`or` is lower precedence than `=` which is lower precedence than `""`

So your code is equivalent to:

```
($a = 0) or 1;
$b = (0 || 1);
```

See the [precedence table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: OMG, that's terrible.

Comment: No. This is documented.

Comment: There wouldn't be much point in having `||` and `or` if they did exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Documentation or not, that's still terrible.

Comment: @Quentin: That's hardly an excuse for it behaving completely non-intuitively!  In what scenario is this useful?

Comment: Maybe this `if($a = functionThatReturnFalse() or $a = functionThatReturnTrue())`. I don't know :/

Comment: Some people (I'm not one of them) like using precedence instead of parenthesis and [everything else](http://tnx.nl/php.html#args) about PHP is unintuitive, so why stop at operators? :).

Comment: This is actually useful now that I know this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the rules of precedence in PHP.  The assignment `=` operator has a lower precedence than the logical `||` operator, but a higher precedence than the logical `OR` operator.  See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the order of precedence

```
// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php