# Laravel Blade {{ $variable or 'Default Text' }} not working with URLs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following code that loops through the user's accounts and display them:

```
@foreach ($accounts as $account)
<tr>
    <td class="user-image hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="{{ $account->profile_pic_url or '/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg' }}" class="img-circle" alt="user-pic" width="48px">
        </a>
    </td>
<tr>
```

When the account does have a profile pic URL, it is shown correctly. But when there's no profile pic, the default URL isn't showed.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: may be this link will be help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or

Comment: what your doing should work - are you sure there isn't an error in the default path? What src is the img trying to load?

Comment: If the user doesn't have an account, what's stored in the DB? Null? An empty string? What you are doing is ok, it should work unless $account->profile_pic_url doesn't evaluate as false.

Comment: There's ins't an error in the default path, I tried to put the full path `https://domain.com/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg`, and it still doesn't work.. @zeratulmdq If the user doesn't have a profile pic, then there's nothing stored in the DB. In my migration, I set the profile_pic_url column to be Null by default.

Comment: Correction: I had an `empty string` in my DB. I modified my migration to make the column nullable and now it works! Thanks @zeratulmdq for the hint.

Comment: You are welcome mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your question, I dare to say you are a bit confused about the 'or' blade syntax. As stated in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data), 'or' is a neat shorcut for "**Echoing Data If It Exists**", but not if it is not null or empty (as I think it is your case)...

E.g., very usually you will fetch models from a database with some of their fields just **EMPTY** ('', 0, false, etc.), what it does not mean that they do not exist. In that cases, the 'or' syntax will just not be for you, because it translates in:

```
{{ isset($name) ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

...and I think you are searching for something like:

```
{{ (isset($name) && $name != '') ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

...or if you certainly know the variable you are evaluating exists, just (for a text field):

```
{{ ($name != '') ? $name : 'Default' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this way:**

`{{ isset($account->profile_pic_url) ? $account->profile_pic_url : '/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg' }}`

**Code:**

```
@foreach ($accounts as $account)
<tr>
    <td class="user-image hidden-xs hidden-sm">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="{{ isset($account->profile_pic_url) ? $account->profile_pic_url : '/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg' }}" class="img-circle" alt="user-pic" width="48px">
        </a>
    </td>
<tr>
```