# OR and && - logical operator php

Tags: php

What i'm doing wrong in this script?

```
if (!is_admin() or !is_product_category() && is_array($arrpags2))
```

I don't understand why don't work

Comment: Operator Precedence. You should group them as you want them to be executed.

Comment: like that: if ((!is_admin() OR !is_product_category()) && is_array($arrpags2))

Comment: The problem is not what's wrong, but what are want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to check these `!is_admin() or !is_product_category()` together with OR operator than you can use like that:

```
if ((!is_admin() OR !is_product_category()) && is_array($arrpags2))
```

If you are trying to check these `!is_product_category() && is_array($arrpags2)` together with && operator than you can use like that:

```
if (!is_admin() OR (!is_product_category() && is_array($arrpags2)))
```

Comment: It is not clear what order OP want it to be. `!is_admin() or !is_product_category()` or `!is_product_category() && is_array($arrpags2)`.

Comment: agreed @Sougata: updated the answer...

Answer (score 0):

With no parenthesis, PHP will evaluate each expression from left to right
you should use parenthesis like this:

```
if 
(
(!is_admin() || !is_product_category()) &&
is_array($arrpags2)
)
```

see this article about [Operator Precedence](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

The && and || operators are intended for Boolean conditions, whereas and and or are intended for control flow.

for more detail see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or)