# PHP While Loop Debugging with Case

Tags: php

i got a bit further into my own little trial and error and wanted to create a while loop that ends if $monster or $du are below "0". I fixed the first problem which was that the loop was permanently in Loop. But now it just ends the moment $du is at or below "0" and not if "monster" is below "0".

What do i have to change?

to make it clear: I want the script to stop if $du is at zero **or** if $monster is at zero. Only one thing hast to be **"true"** to stop it. Because wether the hero kills the monster or the monster kills the hero - the fight is over. 
right now it does only stop when $du is at zero and still goes on and on even if $monster is below zero when at the same time hero is above zero.

```
  <?php

if(isset($_POST['gesendet'])){
// Variablen deklararien und Werte zuweisen.
  $waffe = $_POST['waffe'];
  $monster = 100;
  $du = 70;
  $i = 0;
  $ko = 0;



  switch($waffe){
    case "1":

    while ( $du > 0 OR $monster > 0)  {
      $schaden2 = rand(1,6);
      $dolch = rand(1,4) + 4;
      $du = ($du - $schaden2);
      $monster = ($monster - $dolch);
      $i = $i + 1;

      echo "Runde: " . $i  . "<br>" ;
      echo "Du triffst das Monster mit einem Dolch für " . $dolch . " Schaden.<br>" ;
      echo "Es hat noch " . $monster . " HP<br>" ;
      echo "Das Monster trifft dich für " . $schaden2 . " Schaden.<br>" ;
      echo "Du hast noch " . $du . " HP<br>" ;
    }
    break;

    case "2":

    while ( $du > 0 OR $monster > 0)  {
      $schaden2 = rand(1,6);
      $schwert = rand(1,6) + 2;
      $du = ($du - $schaden2);
      $monster = ($monster - $schwert);
      $i = $i + 1;

      echo "Runde: " . $i  . "<br>" ;
      echo "Du triffst das Monster mit einem Schwert für " . $schwert . " Schaden.<br>" ;
      echo "Es hat noch " . $monster . " HP<br>" ;
      echo "Das Monster trifft dich für " . $schaden2 . " Schaden.<br>" ;
      echo "Du hast noch " . $du . " HP<br>" ;
    }
    break;

    case "3":
      while ( $du > 0 OR $monster > 0)  {
      $schaden2 = rand(1,6);
      $zweihaender = rand(1,6) * 2;
      $du = ($du - $schaden2);
      $monster = ($monster - $zweihaender);
      $i = $i + 1;

      echo "Runde: " . $i  . "<br>" ;
      echo "Du triffst das Monster mit einem Zweihänder für " . $zweihaender . " Schaden.<br>" ;
      echo "Es hat noch " . $monster . " HP<br>" ;
      echo "Das Monster trifft dich für " . $schaden2 . " Schaden.<br>" ;
      echo "Du hast noch " . $du . " HP<br>" ;
    }
    break;


    }
  }





    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'd change

```
while ( $du > 0 OR $monster > 0)  {
```

To

```
while ( $du > 0 || $monster > 0)  {
```

This is because of operator precedence regarding "or" and "||".

Then look at the logic. You are telling the script to stop when either `$du` **or** `$monster` is below zero. If you want the loop to exit when both are below zero then change the code to.

```
while ( $du > 0 && $monster > 0)  {
```

Some links:

- [PHP documentation for operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)
- [Stack Overflow question about precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or/34848592)
- [PHP doc if statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

#### Update

Change your switch statements to this:

```
switch($waffe) {
    case "1":

    while ( $du > 0 && $monster > 0)  {
        $schaden2 = rand(1,6);
        $dolch = rand(1,4) + 4;
        $du = ($du - $schaden2);
        $monster = ($monster - $dolch);
        $i = $i + 1;

        echo "Runde: " . $i  . "<br>" ;
        echo "Du triffst das Monster mit einem Dolch für " . $dolch . " Schaden.<br>" ;
        echo "Es hat noch " . $monster . " HP<br>" ;
        echo "Das Monster trifft dich für " . $schaden2 . " Schaden.<br>" ;
         echo "Du hast noch " . $du . " HP<br>" ;
}
break;
```

Repeat that for all cases in the switch statement (if add them all but then my answer will be long and I'm on my phone).

The logic behind this is that you are getting the script to use this logic:
If `$monster` **and** `$du` are positive then keep running the while loop.
Otherwise someone had died.

So, these are the cases:
If `$monster` is positive and `$du` is positive then keep fighting.
If `$monster` is negative and `$du` is positive then monster is slain.
If `$monster` is positive and `$du` is negative then player is slain.
(This one is unlikely but) If `$monster` is negative and `$du` is negative then both have died.

Your previous code meant that if `$monster` was below zero then the code would carry on running because `$du` was still greater than zero which meant that the whole loop was true.

Consider this example:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 2;
if ($a < 4 || $b < 4)
{
    echo "This will be true.";
}
```

In this example `$a` is not less than 4 but `$b` is which means that the result is true. The way an or statement works is that **one of the two must be true**.

With an and statement **both must be true**. This means that if you did:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 2;
if ($a < 4 && $b < 4)
{
    echo "This will be false and won't run.";
}
```

The above code won't run because `$a` is greater than 4. This will cancel the If statement.

Using and for your while loop means that you will get the desired result.

Comment: no no, i want the script to stop when either $du or $monster is below zero. right now it just stops if $du is below zero. if $monster is below zero and $do is not the script should also stop.

Comment: this is because wether the monster kills the hero or the hero kills the monster - the fight is over.

Comment: @flightofthepenguin have you replaced your whole loop with my code? Replace all the "OR" with "&&" and tell me the result.

Comment: you are right. Sorry - i just didn't get the logic behind this. Shouldn't or also do the trick here? Normally && and || seemed to be clearer to me.

Comment: i mean the loop does work now but it does not work like you said in you answer. now it stops when either $du or $monster is below zero. Just like i wanted to have it but i used && to reach this. I am confused.

Comment: @flightofthepenguin I'm on my phone. So I cannot test this code. What is the problem? What's happening now? Are there any errors?

Comment: @flightofthepenguin I updated my answer to try and explain the logic in more detail.

Comment: no, its all like you explained. thanks for the explanation. i think i just got confused with something but now i got it.

Comment: @flightofthepenguin That's fine, these things happen. I hope what I wrote makes sense to you :) Happy coding :)

Comment: it does. one little thing: what if i also want another echo message when the $monster or $du = zero or below zero. do i have to break the loop with an if statement?

Comment: @flightofthepenguin I don't understand, what would you like to echo? When one of the two variables is less than zero will make the whole loop exit. That means that the next statement is the `break` statement. What you could then have is an echo after the while code block. So you could have `echo ($monster <= 0 && $du > 0 ? "Monster" : ($du <= ? "Player" : "Both")) . " is dead";

Comment: sorry, my english is not good. But that was what i wanted. I found it out while tinkering around. I think i have it now :) thanks again.

Comment: @flightofthepenguin I'm glad I could be of service :) good luck with the rest of your project