# PHP - IF OR Operator not working

Tags: php

I have a super simple PHP code that looks like

```
$location = 'spain';

if ($location != 'usa' || $location != 'spain') {
    echo 'Not Spain';
} else {
    echo 'This is Spain';
}
```

I am expecting it to echo 'This is Spain' but it is not, am I using the OR operator incorrectly?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php ($a || $b TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.)

Comment: [String comparison using == vs. strcmp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333353/608639) and [Logical Operators, || or OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998309/608639)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do `if ($location == 'spain') { echo 'This is Spain'; } else { echo 'Not Spain';}`

Answer (score 1):

No, you should be using AND here.

To understand why, replace the variable `$location` with the actual string `'spain'`:

```
if ('spain' != 'usa' || 'spain' != 'spain') {
    echo 'Not Spain';
} else {
    echo 'This is Spain';
}
```

You can plainly see that the first condition will be `true`, because "spain" is indeed not the same as "usa". That's why you're getting `'Not Spain'` as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Probably in this case you`d want to use AND operator

```
if ($location != 'usa' && $location != 'spain') {
    echo 'Not Spain';
} else {
   echo 'This is Spain';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No its your condition is wrong.

```
$location = 'spain';

if ($location == 'usa' || $location != 'spain') {
    echo 'Not Spain';
} else {
    echo 'This is Spain';
}
```

When you use or condition then it means if any condition is true then it happen so your $location !=' usa' return  true because your  location value not  usa it's sapin

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional expression logic has unnecessary redundancy.  You are performing a full string comparison and to determine if a string is `spain` or not, you only need one condition. (USA's got nothing to do with the logic.)

```
$location = 'spain';
if ($location != 'spain') {
    echo 'Not Spain';
} else {
    echo 'This is Spain';
}
```

If you wish to determine if the string is `spain` or `usa` and output an accurate response, using `==` comparisons and add an `elseif` expression.

```
$location = 'spain';
if ($location == 'spain') {
    echo 'This is Spain';
} elseif ($location == 'usa') {
    echo 'This is USA';
} else {
    echo 'This is neither Spain, nor USA';
}
```