# How can I use 3 or in if condition PHP ? I mean if ( a or b or c )

Tags: php

I have below code.

```
 if ( is_woocommerce() or is_cart() != true)
```

---

I want also check is_account_page true with or operator.How can I use 3 function in condition with or operator?

```
   is_account_page()
```

Comment: `if (is_woocommerce() || !is_cart() || is_account_page())`?

Comment: Could you share in what situation (what those functions should return) for the if-expression to be evaluated as true? Just want to make sure we have the full picture. And are you aware [of the differences between the `or` and the `||` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or)?

Comment: I want to read body when only if there is no true in parantes.Also I want to learn using parantes in php.I mean I want to write every condition like write to paper for maths.can you give me resource?

Comment: No idea what you mean by _“I want to write every condition like write to paper for maths”_, so no idea what resources to possibly give you here either.

Comment: So you want the if-statement to be evaluated as true only if none of the functions return true? I'm trying to understand _exactly_ what you're looking for, but you're being slightly unclear in your question/comments. Please be as detailed as possible. Have you read the manual about [expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) and [comparison operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
if ( is_woocommerce() or is_cart() != true or is_account_page() )
```

Comment: How can I use paranthesises like maths? I want to learn write every condition like write to paper? can you learn it me or give me good resource?

Comment: yes you can do that, but you can only use parentheses

Comment: but can you give me an example?

Comment: like `if( (a == b) or ( c == ( a + b ) or ( a - c ) == d ) )`