# Boolean has wrong value after operation

Tags: php

I have a form used to change settings on a Raspberry Pi, and I am trying to read values from a web interface, and then use that to pass it to a python script to make the necessary changes.

I also have a boolean which checks if any values have actually changed which then triggers a reboot process.

But the boolean is always false, and I cannot really figure out why.

I have a JSON already parsed which reads the values from disk, that works fine. Since I could not figure out what may be wrong, I added some more echos to help with this, and I am really confused why the `reboot_needed` is not true. It is initialized to `false`.

```
    $ssid = $_POST['ssid'];        
    $reboot_needed = $reboot_needed or ($ssid != $json->{"ssid"});
    echo $reboot_needed ? "ssid true<br>" : "ssid false<br>";
    echo ($ssid != $json->{"ssid"}) ? "SSID should now be true" : "SSID should not change value";
```

Sample output:

```
ssid false
SSID should now be true
```

Those two are, at least from my understanding, completely contradictory. One states the second part of the `or` was `true`, whereas the other states that my variable is still `false`. I have no idea what's happening here.

Edit: I just replaced the `or` with `||`, and now the values are what I thought they should be. Whats the difference?

Comment: Can you please add your `$json` object value?

Comment: Note: I just tested with `||` instead, and that worked. But I have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: We can't see the initial value of `$reboot_needed` (where do you first declare it in your script?) or the content of `$json` it's tricky to know what's really going on. And `$ssid` isn't used in your logic at all, so it's hard to work out the significance of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998330/5947043 might help to explain the `or` vs `||` thing

Comment: `reboot_needed` is initialized to false. `$ssid` is used in the second part of the `or`

Comment: Sorry I missed that $ssid. Anyway the answer is in the precedence used by the `or` operator.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Logical Operators, || or OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998309/logical-operators-or-or)

Comment: It sort of fixes my problem, but my understanding of why this happened, considering I encapsulated it in brackets is wonky. I assumed that brackets have the highest precedence always, and they are not listed in the link, so hard to see if they are between `or` and `||`

Comment: It's the first part of your expression which is the issue, not the bracketed part. You're expecting it to be interpreted like `$reboot_needed = ($reboot_needed or ($ssid != $json->{"ssid"}));` but - as per the near-identical example in the link I posted, what actually happens is `($reboot_needed = $reboot_needed) or ($ssid != $json->{"ssid"});`

Comment: Why use `$json->{"ssid"}` syntax to mean `$json->ssid`?